# Set width of entry object in an optimal way the string is fully visible

Tags: python, tkinter, width, data-entry

I have following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

def resize(lbl):
    USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="User input",
                                  prompt="Please enter your message here:")
    lbl['state'] = 'normal'
    lbl.insert(0, f"Text was \'{USER_INP}\'.")
    lbl['state'] = 'readonly'
    lbl['width'] = 50



top = Tk()
lbl_entry = Entry(top, state="readonly", justify='center', width=10)
lbl_entry.grid(column=0, row=1)


bt_adjust = Button(top, text = "Resize Entry", command=lambda:resize(lbl_entry))
bt_adjust.grid(column=0, row=0)

top.mainloop()
```

After pressing the button `bt_adjust` the width of the `Entry` object is adjusting automatically. Is their a way to set the width dynamically in that way the text is fully displayed on the `Entry` element but if the width would be a little smaller the text wouldn't be fully displayed anymore?

Comment: Just change the last line of `resize()` to `lbl['width'] = len(USER_INP)`.

Comment: @martineau `len(USER_INP)` does not include the beginning `"Text was '"` and the ending `"'."`.  Just set `lbl['width'] = 0` will make the width to fit the text.

Comment: @acw1668: Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? By using `len()` to adjusting automatically resizing.

> After pressing the button `bt_adjust` the width of the Entry object is
> adjusting automatically.

code in line 10:

```
lbl['width'] = f'{len(USER_INP)}
```

Screenshot before resizing:

[image]

AScreenshot after resizing:

[image]